# How do I get .cshtml files to throw build errors in a .NET 6 Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working in a .NET 6 web API project, using .cshtml files with the RazorLight package for email templates. If I have an error in my .cshtml file, such as referencing a property that does not exist in the model, Visual Studio picks it up and gives me the red squiggly line. But when I build the project, I have no errors.

This means that if I change the model's properties, I would not be warned about issues in my cshtml file. How can I get the build to fail if there is an error in the cshtml file?

I've tried setting the Build Action for the cshtml files, but this hasn't changed anything. I also tried registering razor pages in the startup.cs file, using `services.AddRazorPages();`.

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: This is just how Visual Studio is, I've ran into this issue before. Razor is templating in things to the HTML/CSS/JS so there really isn't much that the dotnet compiler is checking for as its not actually compiling those files. It is taking the razor to generate the HTML, valid or invalid all. JetBrains Rider is a lot better at this but this is because of their own proprietary tech and not the dotnet compiler

Comment: The best solution is to run the project locally , and then open up the developer tools within your web browser and inspect the various bugs and error messages. If something was not templated in properly, the console will report this as being `undefined` or some other html/js error. Then you will know exactly where to look in your .cshtml files to verify that the razor is correct. Its a pain but that's how it goes